# Tabulator rowFormatter callback disable cell edit functionality

Tags: javascript, tabulator

everything was working good in tabulator grid view

but when i changed the view of the table by rowFormatter callback the cells becomes static and they were not editable.

The rows are also not deleting after i changed the layout

this is the table format when cells were editable and delete button was working fine

[image]

and this is the new layout of the table

[image]

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table2", {
    data:tabledata, //assign data to table
    columns:[{title : "FullURL", field : "FullURL", editor : "input"},{title : "PageSlug", field : "PageSlug", editor : "input"},{title : "Button1", field : "Button1", editor : "input"},{title : "Link 1", field : "Link 1", editor : "input"},{title : "Button2", field : "Button2", editor : "input"},{title : "Link 2", field : "Link 2", editor : "input"},{formatter : 'buttonCross', align : 'center', title : 'Actions', headerSort : false, cellClick : function(e, cell){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?"))cell.getRow().delete();}}],
    layout:"fitColumns",
    tooltips:true,
    addRowPos:"top",          //when adding a new row, add it to the top of the table
    pagination:"local",
    paginationSize:15,         //allow 7 rows per page of data
    movableColumns:true,
    cellClick:function(e, cell){

    console.log(cell);
    },
    rowFormatter:function(row){
        var element = row.getElement(),
        data = row.getData(),
        width = element.offsetWidth,
        rowTable, cellContents;


        var actionsBtnDelete=element.lastChild;

        while(element.firstChild) element.removeChild(element.firstChild);

        //define a table layout structure and set width of row
        rowTable = document.createElement("table")
        rowTable.style.width = (width - 18) + "px";

        rowTable.style.marginTop ="6px";
        rowTable.style.marginLeft ="4px";
       

        rowTabletr = document.createElement("tr");

 
        //add row data on right hand side
        cellContents = `
        <td style="">
            <div>
                <div style='margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom:1px;padding-right: 8px;'> 
                    <strong>PageSlug:</strong> ` + data.PageSlug + `'
                </div>

                <div style='margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom:1px;padding-right: 8px;'>
                    <strong>Button1:</strong> ` + data.Button1 + `
                </div>

                <div style='margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom:1px;padding-right: 8px;'>
                    <strong>Button2:</strong> ` + data.Button2 + `
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </td>

        <td style="margin-left:4px;">
            <div>
                

                <div style='margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom:1px;'>
                    <strong>FullURL:</strong> ` + data[Object.keys(data)[0]] + `
                </div>
                
                <div style='margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom:1px;'>
                    <strong>Link 1:</strong> ` + data["Link 1"] + `
                </span>

                <div style='margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom:1px;'>
                    <strong>Link 2:</strong> ` + data["Link 2"] + `
                </div>
            </div>


        </td>

        <td>
            `+actionsBtnDelete.innerHTML+`
        </td>
        `;

        

        rowTabletr.innerHTML = cellContents;

        rowTable.appendChild(rowTabletr);

        //append newly formatted contents to the row
        element.append(rowTable);
    },
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your row formatter removes the whole content of the row including all of the cells:

```js
while(element.firstChild) element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
```

and then replaces it with your own table element.

The cells and their editors are managed by a complex set of event bindings and modules. If you delete the entire contents of the row then you might as well just use a standard list element instead of a Tabulator, because you have removed most of its functionality as a table